# Modifying Sphinx Output

Tags: javascript, python, html, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have a RST source file that has several *term* constructs like such:

```
:term:`memory manager` ...
```

Sphinx is generating HTML from the RST file like this:

```
<a class="reference internal" href="#term-memory-manager">
    <span class="xref std std-term">memory manager</span>
</a>
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to modify the output Sphinx is generating. Specifically, I just need to add an additional class to the span element surrounding 'memory manager'.

Are there any resources on how to do this?